# Highchart - Column chart - Drilldown event fires many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have implemented column chart using highchart and trying to show another series of data in drilldown. Drilldown is working fine but event triggers many times. For example: If you click a bar second time, then drilldown event will trigger 2 times. Drilldown event is increasing based on clicks.

And i don't know how to stop the event.(stopPropagation isn't working).

```
events: {
  drilldown: function(e) {
    if (!e.seriesOptions) {
      chart = this;
      chart.showLoading('<div class="loading-modal loading-modal-wrapper"><div class="loading-title">Loading...</div></div>');
      const param = {
        method: 'Get',
        url: `/test/`
      };
      service.ajax(param, resp => {
        // Show the loading label
        formatSeriesData(e.point.category, resp);
        $timeout(() => {
          chart.xAxis[0].categories = drilldownCategories;
          chart.xAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
            text: e.point.category
          });
          chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldownSeriesData);
          chart.hideLoading();
          chart.applyDrilldown();
        });
      }, () => {
        $log.log("API data failed!");
      });

    }
  },
    drillup: () => {
      chart.xAxis[0].categories = $ctrl.categories;
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
angular.js:14199 TypeError: Cannot read property 'xAxis' of null
    at a.Chart.q.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown (drilldown.js:10)

    at a.Chart.q.addSeriesAsDrilldown (drilldown.js:10)
```

Can anyone please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: @ewollen Do have any idea? how to stop/destroy highchart events?

Comment: I have upgraded the version of highChart(6.0.4). Now it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. And, it really took my head off. No need to upgrade the highchart version.

While making the chartconfig do the below task,

```
if(chartInitialized){           
        chartInitialized = false;
    }
    else{
         chartConfig.chart.events = Object.create({});
    }
```

and initialize the variable to true on load. 
Thanks :)